# Get matlab to show square roots (i.e. 2^(1/2) instead of 1.414)

Tags: matlab

I have a few simple equations that I want to pipe through matlab. But I would like to get exact answers, because these values are expected to be used and simplified later on.

Right now Matlab shows `sqrt(2.0)` as `1.1414` instead of something like `2^(1/2)` as I would like.

I tried turning on `format rat` but this is dangerous becasue it shows `sqrt(2)` as `1393/985` without any sort of warning.

There is "symbolic math" but it seems like overkill.

All I want is that `2 + sqrt(50)` would return something like `2 + 5 * (2)^(1/2)` and even my 5 years old CASIO calculator can do this!

So what can I do to get `2 + sqrt(50)` evaluate to `2 + 5 * (2)^(1/2)` in matlab?

Comment: Symbolic math, or use Wolfram Alpha. Matlab is geared towards numerics.

Comment: The answer to the question what is the square root of 2 is 1.414.  Not 2^(1/2), that is the question repeated back to you.

Comment: @Matt that was just an example, a better example is `2 + sqrt(50)`

Comment: why would a thousands of dollars worth of numerical software leave the square root uncalculated? What if I want to know the answer? What should I do then?

Comment: Matlab by default deals with `double` types and the square root of 2 cannot be exactly represented as a double (it contains an infinite number of decimal places in binary). So `sqrt()` doesn't compute the 'exact' square root, it computes a numerical approximation to the square root, and you lose the 'exact' value as soon as you do the computation. If you want to retain exact values use symbolic math - that's what it's there for! Roughly speaking, numerics are faster but inexact; symbolics are slower but exact.

Comment: @user10607 my comment still stands.  All you are doing is asking for Matlab to repeat your question back to you.  `2 + sqrt(50)` is about `9.07`, not `2 + 50^(1/2)`.  That is simply the question repeated again.  The question I have is why do you need Matlab to show it to you that way?  There is probably a better way to solve your actual problem then adjusting the formatting of Matlab.  Perhaps a different solver is what you are truly after.

Comment: @Matt I wanted Matlab to simplify my expression, so that I could write it out on paper and work on it more. I wanted it to transform `2 + sqrt(50)` into `2 + 5 * sqrt(2)`. So its not just the question repeated back to me. You can see that some analysis has been made and the expression is changed. Well, anyway, I already understand that Matlab is not really suited for this type of simplification. Oh well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [@Oleg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158086/get-matlab-to-show-square-roots-i-e-21-2-instead-of-1-414#comment56062856_34158086) use symbolic math.

```
x=sym('2')+sqrt(sym('50'))
x =
5*2^(1/2) + 2
```

The average time on ten thousand iterations through this expression is 1.2 milliseconds, whilst the time for the numeric expression (`x=2+sqrt(50)`) is only 0.4 micro seconds, i.e. a factor of ten thousand faster.

I did pre-run the symbolic expression 50 times, because, as Oleg points out in his [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158086/get-matlab-to-show-square-roots-i-e-21-2-instead-of-1-414#comment56063084_34158208) the symbolic engine needs some warming up. The first run through your expression took my pc almost 2 seconds.

I would therefore recommend using numeric equations due to the huge difference in calculation time. Only use symbolic expressions when you are forced to (e.g. simplifying expressions for a paper) and then use a symbolic computation engine like Maple or Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: There is an initial load time of the sumbolic engine, it should be faster of subsequent executions.

Comment: so I will just have to wrap all the distinct steps of calculation up into `sym(.....)`. This is like the moment when I start singing to stop myself from crying.

Comment: @user10607 You do not need to. See my answer which is an alternative approach.

Comment: @user10607 well, for loose expressions, yes. If you've got loads of them, see my last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

Matlab main engine is not symbolic but numeric.

Symbolic toolbox. Create expression in `x` and subs `x = 50`

```
syms x
f = 2+sqrt(x)

subs(f,50)
ans =
50^(1/2) + 2
```